# Log or Toast doesent work Android Studio

Tags: java, android, logging, toast

I am writing small app in android studio and i want to print system log or show toast in one function but it doesent work in other functions it is working .. here is code of first function

```
private void checkBarcodeLength(){
    if (containerbarcode_ausladen_string.length()==8){
        filno_frombarcode = containerbarcode_ausladen_string.substring(1, 4);
        if (filno_frombarcode.startsWith("0")){
            filno_frombarcode = filno_frombarcode.substring(1,3);
        }
        checkFillocation();
    }else if (containerbarcode_ausladen_string.startsWith("11")) {
        filno_frombarcode = containerbarcode_ausladen_string.substring(5, 8);
        if (filno_frombarcode.startsWith("0")){
            filno_frombarcode = filno_frombarcode.substring(1,3);
        }
        checkFillocation();
    } else if (containerbarcode_ausladen_string.startsWith("AP")) {
        filno_frombarcode = containerbarcode_ausladen_string.substring(7, 10);
        if (filno_frombarcode.startsWith("0")){
            filno_frombarcode = filno_frombarcode.substring(1,3);
        }
        checkFillocation();
    } else {
            removeItemDB();
        }
}
```

and then in this function it doesent work

```
private void checkFillocation(){
    Toast.makeText(ausladen.this,"Started searching for location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    filno_frombarcode_long = Integer.parseInt(filno_frombarcode);

    /**Latitude -100m and +100m from my location*/
    point1 = (Double.parseDouble(latout_ausladen) - 0.0008995);
    point2 = (Double.parseDouble(latout_ausladen) + 0.0008995);

    /**Longitude -100m and +100m from my location*/
    point3 = (Double.parseDouble(lonout_ausladen) - 0.0013190);
    point4 = (Double.parseDouble(lonout_ausladen) + 0.0013190);

    /**Find Filiale from barcode*/
    getfilno = myDb.getfilNo(filno_frombarcode_long);

    /**Find Filiale near my location*/
    findfil_nearmylocation = myDb.findfil_nearmyloc(point1, point2, point3, point4);

    /**Get Filiale nummer from DB*/
    if (getfilno.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id_filno = getfilno.getInt(getfilno.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            filno = getfilno.getString(getfilno.getColumnIndex("filno"));
            fillat = getfilno.getDouble(getfilno.getColumnIndex("fillat"));
            fillon = getfilno.getDouble(getfilno.getColumnIndex("fillon"));

        } while (getfilno.moveToNext());
    }
    getfilno.close();

    /**Get Filiale nummer by my location from DB*/
    if (findfil_nearmylocation.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id_filno_bymyloc = findfil_nearmylocation.getInt(findfil_nearmylocation.getColumnIndex("_id"));
            filno_bymyloc = findfil_nearmylocation.getString(findfil_nearmylocation.getColumnIndex("filno"));
            fillat_bymyloc = findfil_nearmylocation.getDouble(findfil_nearmylocation.getColumnIndex("fillat"));
            fillon_bymyloc = findfil_nearmylocation.getDouble(findfil_nearmylocation.getColumnIndex("fillon"));

        } while (findfil_nearmylocation.moveToNext());
    }

    findfil_nearmylocation.close();

    System.out.print("Barcode: " + containerbarcode_ausladen_string);
    System.out.print("FilNo: " + filno_frombarcode);
    System.out.print("FilNo from geoLocation: " + filno_bymyloc);

    //No Filiale nummer in barcode
    if (getfilno.getCount()== 0) {
        removeItemDB();
        Log.d(anmelden.class.getName(),"count 0" );

    //No Filiale nummer by my location
    }else if ( filno_bymyloc == null ){
        removeItemDB();
        Log.d(anmelden.class.getName(),"filnobymyloc== null" );

    //Found Filiale in barcode and with my location
    } else if (getfilno.getCount()== 1 && filno.matches(filno_bymyloc) ){
        removeItemDB();
        Log.d(anmelden.class.getName(),"count 1, filno=filnobymyloc" );

    //Found Filiale in barcode but my location null
    } else if (getfilno.getCount()== 1 && filno_bymyloc == null) {
        removeItemDB();
        Log.d(anmelden.class.getName(),"count 1,  filnobymyloc==null" );

    //No Filiale in barcode but found Filiale with my location
    } else if (getfilno.getCount()== 0 && filno.matches(filno_bymyloc) ) {
        removeItemDB();
        Log.d(anmelden.class.getName(), "No Filiale in barcode, Found Filiale with my location");

    //No GPS position
    } else if (latout_ausladen.matches("0.0")){
        removeItemDB();
        Log.d(anmelden.class.getName(), "No GPS position found");

    //Falsche Filiale
    } else {

        //Play sound three times
        mediaPlayer(getApplicationContext(), sound3);

        //Remove item from ListView
        myDb.ausladen("\"" + containerbarcode_ausladen_string + "\"", formateddate_ausladen, "scan",
                latout_ausladen,lonout_ausladen, "ausgeladen","notime",
                lkwnummer_ausladen);

        //Refresh ListView
        loadListView();

        //Set barcode to empty
        etxt_ausladen_barcode.setText("");

        Log.d(anmelden.class.getName(),"Falsche Filiale");
    }
}
```

Thanks all for reading and helping :)

Comment: Toast can be run only in the UI thread, are you calling your `checkFillocation` in an `AsyncTask`? Please show also the code where you call this method. thanks

Comment: Probably `checkFillocation()` is never called, because the execution always takes the `else` branch,  where `removeItemDB()` is. You can put some log output in the different branches of `checkBarcodeLength()` to test it.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should use Android Log and not System.out.print(). For example - `Log.d("Test", "Barcode: " + containerbarcode_ausladen_string);`

2) Not sure why your Toast doesn't show up - Can you put a break point and make sure it hit and that it is on the main thread? If it is not on the main thread you should post it to the main thread.

Comment: I have put toast message in onCreate then in all other functions and in all other it works but in this dont .... and the Log.d from this function doesent too work and in other functions it work :S

Comment: Are you sure you actually go into that function? Put a break point inside to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

For logging your app you must use Android Log instead System.out.print(). It has different reach levels, like "debug", "warning" or "error". Then you can filter this levels and look only for that info that you want to see using the Logcat.

For example, if you want to log an error, you can simply

```
Log.e("YourTag", "Put your message error here");
```

The '.e' means that you are logging an error (use '.w' for warnings or '.d' for debug messages, etc).
The first parameter is the tag, you can also filter by this field on the Android Monitor Logcat.

The second parameter is the message you want to log.
Here you have the basic doc for logging with Android Studio Logcat: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Toast only can be used on the main Thread, so calling it from other thread, like an AsyncTask won't show up anything. Nevertheless, it is not a good practise using Toast messages for logging.

I hope it helps!

Comment: i have tested all of this but nothing worked for me in this function ...

Comment: Well, that means that the execution is not reaching that function. Try using the debugger why is this happening.

Comment: i have found the error was by me i have converted number from base 10 to base 62 and then checked length from base 62 number not from base 10 and that was why my function is not called.

Comment: Thank you for time spent to my problem bro :)